# Drawing multiple GeoJSON lines with Mapbox and Nominatim

Tags: jquery, mapbox-gl-js, nominatim

I'm trying to draw a street when a user clicks on it on the map that uses OSM data and is rendered by Mapbox. I get the coordinates from the click and send them to the server, and then i return the LineStrings, that Nominatim provides for specific street. I have an issue with longer streets: they seem to be incomplete(eg. 100m of correctly drawn line, then 100 of the street is missing and then again normally drawn line), some longer streets can be made of even as much as 10 or more segments. In my opinion this problem can be caused because osm has incomplete data(though i doubt that) or i don't draw/load the data correctly. My code looks like that:

```js
map.on("click", function(e) {
      //get coordinates and send them to the server.

      function getRequest() {
        return $.ajax({
          url: "/street",
          data: clickCoords,
        });
      };

      $.when(getRequest()).done(function(response, status, jqXHR) {
        streetGEOJSON = response;
        var feat = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < streetGEOJSON.length; i++) {
          feat[i] = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "LineString",
              "coordinates": streetGEOJSON[i]
            }
          }
        }
        var lines = {
          "type": "geojson",
          "data": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": feat
          }
        }
        map.addSource("street", lines);

        map.addLayer({
          "id": "street",
          "type": "line",
          "source": "street",
          "filter": ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
          "layout": {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "round"
          },
          "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8
          }
        });
      });
```

example of wronly drawn street: http://prntscr.com/erfwhr

also noticed this: http://prntscr.com/erg0r0 . 
the data passed to as get response can be as much as 3000 or more characters long. i'm guessing that's the problem, and the browser doesn't wait for all the coordinates..

Any help or insight would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post the answer if anyone encounters similar problems :) the problem was not in the request from the server but in nominatim reducing search results so the solution was to include &dedupe=0 in get request for nominatim.